# Click in a button to call a main activity of another Project

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

In resume, in the first activity I have a login button and when i click on it I want to call the second main activity of another Project.

This is the Manifest of my first activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication_login"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.enamul.qrcode"
    >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication_login">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="program">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.enamul.qrcode.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.myapplication_login"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And the manifest of my second is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.enamul.qrcode">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

And I have an error in my first manifest that is:*Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.enamul.qrcode.MainActivity, was not found in the project or the libraries*

How can I fix it? Someone can help me?

I already add the intent in the code of the first activity like this:

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, com.example.enamul.qrcode.MainActivity);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

First is with the package name of the application you want to open:

```
button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    // intent will be null if no intent is found for the package
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.enamul.qrcode");
    startActivity(intent);
});
```

Second is to define what your activity will resolve to. For the activity you want to open add an intent filter that defines a scheme and host:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:scheme="something"
            android:host="somethingelse" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To open it on a button click from another app:

```
button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("something://somethingelse"));
    startActivity(intent);
});
```

Although you should use a host and scheme that is more sensible for your app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Intents. Like this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/xxx");
Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

try {
    startActivity(likeIng);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/xxx")));
}
```